# Creating Actions from UIActionSheets help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am using two UIAction sheets within my current project. I can get one to work perfectly fine but when i insert a second action sheet it runs the same arguements as the first. How do i define the actionsheets seperatly?

```
-(IBAction) phoneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    // open a dialog with just an OK button
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Phone: %@",phone],nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
    [actionSheet release];  
}

-(IBAction) mapButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    // open a dialog with just an OK button
    UIActionSheet *mapActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                        otherButtonTitles:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Map"],nil];
    mapActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [mapActionSheet showInView:self.view];  // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
    [mapActionSheet release];   
}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if(buttonIndex == 0){
            NSString *callPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone];
            NSLog(@"Calling: %@", callPhone);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:callPhone]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIActionSheet` is a subview of `UIView` and therefore you could use the `tag` property.

Answer (score 0):

Make the actionSheets instance variables and test in the delegate method which action sheet was returned.

Alternatively, write your own subclass of `UIActionSheet` (and `UIAlert`, which suffers from the same annoyance), to send callbacks to a delegate object when the return is captured.